X/Twitter Create media returning 400 Bad request code 214
const createXMedia = async (image: Node) => {

  const oauth = Oauth({
  consumer: {
    key: process.env.X_CONSUMER_KEY,
    secret: process.env.X_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  },
  signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
  hash_function: (baseString, key) => createHmac("sha1", key).update(baseString).digest("base64"),
});

  const url = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";

  const token = {
    key: process.env.X_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    secret: process.env.X_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  };

  const headers = oauth.toHeader(
    oauth.authorize(
      {
        url,
        method: "POST",
      },
      token,
    ),
  );

  const mediaFile = await fetch(image.featuredImage.url).then(async (e) => {
    const arrayBufferImg = await e.arrayBuffer();

    return Buffer.from(arrayBufferImg).toString("base64");
  });

  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("media_category", "tweet_image");
  formData.append("media_data", mediaFile);

  const mediaResponse = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: headers["Authorization"],
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "base64",
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  });

  if(mediaResponse.status >=400) {
    throw new Error(`${mediaResponse.status} ${mediaResponse.statusText} ${await     mediaResponse.text()}`);
  }

  const mediaResponseBody: IXMediaPost = await mediaResponse.json();

  return mediaResponseBody;
 };

Currently, mediaResponse returns a 400 bad request with the code 214 from twitter, not sure what might be causing it.
{"errors":[{"code":214,"message":"Bad request."}]}

Looked at every single guide I could find but nothing seemed to fix the issue. Posting tweets with just text seems to work fine but not images
Tried multiple images, even ones locally, tried using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, tried using binary instead of base64, but nada...

Bump, really need help here..
